# Which activities offer the most professor XP per activity point?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

I’d like to maximize my professor level as early as possible to max out my availiable supply of activity points. What activities in the monastery offer the most professor XP per activity point I spend on them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tl;dr: Tournaments > Choir Practice/Sharing a Meal > Cooking. Faculty Training gives no XP. Gardening yields XP at zero activity point cost, but throttled to once per week. Fishing is effectively infinite/limited by bait, not AP.**

Regardless of which of the many actives you do, increasing your professor level will be time consuming and take a good bit of grinding. However, the [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fireemblem/comments/cj37q9/breakdown_of_professor_xp_yields_useful/) community has a collection of all the activities and the amount of experience they provide.

**Fishing**
Fishing provides some experience, and does not consume any activity points. So this can be a grindy way to increase your professor level, given you have the patience. The experience that is provided varies on the fish that is caught.

- T. Loach, A. Herring, W. Trout, A. Goby, C. Crayfish: **10xp**
- Q. Loach, A. Pike, C. Gar: **20xp**
- Bullhead, Golden Fish: **30xp**
- Platinum Fish: **40xp**

In addition to reddit, [this guide](https://gamewith.net/fire-emblem-three-houses/article/show/10326) recommends this route through breeding season. You can check whether or not it is breeding season by the fishing icon on the calendar. During this season, you have the chance to obtain multiple fish with a single bait. This will increase the amount of experience relative to the number of fish you catch.

**Gardening**
Gardening will provide between **100xp** and **300xp**, depending on the cultivation you select when planting the seeds. The downside to this though is that you can only cash in the experience the next time you visit the monastery.

**Cooking/Eating Meals**
Regardless of motivation or support levels, sharing and cooking meals will provide **200xp** and **150xp** respectively. However, since this costs activity points, it's recommended to use them sparingly with units you which to build motivation and support with.

**Choir**
Regardless of motivation or support levels, participating in choir practice will provide **200xp**.

**Tournament**
Winning the weekly tournament will provide **300xp**. Unlike other activities, this one is repeatable! So you can continually obtain **300xp** for each activity point you use

**Random Items**
Occasionally you can find items - such as books, tea leaves, or food - around the monastery. On the map, these are indicated by a blue sparkle (just like lost items). When you pick these items up, you will gain some tidbits of information and anywhere between **100xp** and **500xp**

**Instructing**
Towards the beginning of each month, you are given the chance to answer questions some of your students may have. You are guaranteed at least **1000xp** for answering the question. If you answer correctly and the student's motivation increased by 50 points instead of 25, you will obtain **1200xp** instead.

Comment: Great info! I edited in a Tl;dr to more effectively surface the specific information I was asking for. Thanks!

Comment: And I *think* the lost items piece is slightly off - I’ve never gotten xp for returning a lost and found item, but I’ve found books lying around the monastery that yield xp - the blue sparkles look the same as lost items, as well as the same as the random food and seed and tea drops you occasionally find scattered around the place.

Comment: The Fishing section could be clarified a little. The event is called "Fistful of Fish." The best strategy for increasing your professor points is to unlock the merchants as soon as possible, then buy every possible fishing bait each month. The Fistful of Fish event occurs on day 10 of month 8 and day 7 of month 12. When these events happen, use up all your fishing bait on those days. The event means every bait will catch at least two fish, sometimes up to four, thus more than doubling the exp gained compared to fishing normally. As ever, reject the first and second fish if blue.